# Not Able to run react native application after installation of react native camera for bar code scanning

Tags: react-native, react-native-camera

BUILD FAILED in 3s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:preDebugBuild'.

  > Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
  >   Could not resolve project :react-native-camera.
  >    Required by:
  >        project :app
  >   Cannot choose between the following variants of project :react-native-camera:
  >         - generalDebugRuntimeElements
  >         - mlkitDebugRuntimeElements
  >       All of them match the consumer attributes:
  >         - Variant 'generalDebugRuntimeElements' capability odfl_poc:react-native-camera:unspecified:
  >             - Unmatched attributes:
  >                 - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'generalDebug' but wasn't required.
  >                 - Found react-native-camera 'general' but wasn't required.
  >             - Compatible attributes:
  >                 - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' and found compatible value 'debug'.
  >                 - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found compatible value 'Aar'.
  >                 - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-runtime' and found compatible value 'java-runtime'.
  >         - Variant 'mlkitDebugRuntimeElements' capability odfl_poc:react-native-camera:unspecified:
  >             - Unmatched attributes:
  >                 - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'mlkitDebug' but wasn't required.
  >                 - Found react-native-camera 'mlkit' but wasn't required.
  >             - Compatible attributes:
  >                 - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' and found compatible value 'debug'.
  >                 - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found compatible value 'Aar'.
  >                 - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-runtime' and found compatible value 'java-runtime'.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

I am using react native 0.60.4 , gradle 3.4.1,react-native-camera": "^3.0.0"
can anyone please suggest me why I am not able to run my application after installed of react camera or suggest me is there an alternate way to scan the bar code in react native. Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this your first installation? 
Have you used your project before installing react-native-camera?
If yes, have you cleaned gradlew before install?
Have you checked if react-native-camera has additional configuration steps ?

Comment: @AndréPinto first off all Thanks for your response. I have installed first time in my project and cleaned the gradlew as well after installation. I just installed react-native-camera in command prompt haven't follow any additional steps